# Spring Constructor Injection throws an error when more than one constructor has @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

Spring documentation says this:

> Only one annotated constructor per class can be marked as required, but multiple non-required constructors can be annotated. In that case, each is considered among the candidates and Spring uses the greediest constructor whose dependencies can be satisfied — that is, the constructor that has the largest number of arguments. The constructor resolution algorithm is the same as for non-annotated classes with overloaded constructors, just narrowing the candidates to annotated constructors.

I tested it and I get an error as soon as I have another constructor marked by `@Autowired`

```
package com.example.demo.constructorinjection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ConstructorInjectComponent {   

private InjectionServiceOne injectionServiceOne;

private InjectionServiceTwo injectionServiceTwo;

@Autowired(required = true)
public constructorInjectComponent(InjectionServiceOne injectionServiceOne,
        InjectionServiceTwo injectionServiceTwo) {
    this.injectionServiceOne = injectionServiceOne;
    this.injectionServiceTwo = injectionServiceTwo;
}

@Autowired(required = false)
public constructorInjectComponent(InjectionServiceTwo injectionServiceTwo) {
    this.injectionServiceTwo = injectionServiceTwo;
}

@Autowired(required = false)
public constructorInjectComponent(InjectionServiceOne injectionServiceOne) {
    this.injectionServiceOne = injectionServiceOne;
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000L)
public void allFieldsConstructorInjectionTest() {
    System.err.println("constructorInjection " + injectionServiceOne.method() + " " + injectionServiceTwo.method());
}
}
```

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'constructorInjectComponent': Invalid autowire-marked constructor: public com.example.demo.constructorinjection.constructorInjectComponent(com.example.demo.constructorinjection.InjectionServiceOne). Found constructor with 'required' Autowired annotation already: public com.example.demo.constructorinjection.constructorInjectComponent(com.example.demo.constructorinjection.InjectionServiceOne,com.example.demo.constructorinjection.InjectionServiceTwo)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:314) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]

Question:

Why can't I have more than one constructors marked with `@Autowired`? Spring documentation clearly says I can have more than one constructor marked with `@Autowired`.

Comment: Strange.  It seems to be saying that you're trying to create a second required constructor, but your @Autowired annotation clearly says that you aren't.  My guess is that this is some subtlety with Spring or simply a bug.  If this were me and I got no other help, I think I'd be digging in with the debugger to try to figure out what Spring is doing.  But that's sure yucky.  Best of luck figuring this out.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the response. I am trying to prepare for Spring Professional Certification. I will try to find an example online that has multiple constructors marked by `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Autowired` is processed by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which its javadoc has better description of this behaviour:

> Only one constructor (at max) of any given bean class may declare this
>   annotation with the 'required' parameter set to true, indicating the
>   constructor to autowire when used as a Spring bean.

This statement talks about the case when `'required' = true`.

So if `'required' = true` , only one constructor (at max) can declare `@Autowired`.

> If multiple non-required constructors declare the annotation, they
>   will be considered as candidates for autowiring. The constructor with
>   the greatest number of dependencies that can be satisfied by matching
>   beans in the Spring container will be chosen.

This statement implies the other case (i.e. `'required' = false`).

So  if `'required' = false` , it allows to have multiple constructors.

---

You can see this checking logic in the source codes of this [for-loop](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9e1ed6c7718d38c4b9fe5f75921abad33264307c/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L302) , which the codes are well written which is quite easy to understand.

Comment: So what are you saying? You are making two contradictory statements.

Comment: So what do you mean ? How to contradict ? Maybe it is a language problem since I am not the native English speaker. I don't aware what contradict. Anyway , I try to rephrase it in my updated answer . Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. So now the question is, how does your answer resolve my issue? I already have one constructor with required = true and two other constructors with required = false.

Comment: My answer tell you the rule when `required = true`. So the rule is that if you have one  constructor  with required = true , only one constructor (at max) can declare with `@Autowired`. But now you annotate other two constructors  with `@Autowired` , you totally have 3 constructors declared with `@Autowired` , so it does not obey this rule and fails. So , does it make sense now if rephrased in this way?

Comment: You are allowed to have many constructors with `@Autowired(required = false)`. If you have constructor with `@Autowired(required = true)`, then you are not allowed to have any other constructors with `@Autowired` annotation. That is what @KenChan is trying to clarify, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests, and this is what I found.

Only one constructor can be marked with `@Autowired` (where required=true will be the default). And that's it. No other constructor can be marked with `@Autowired` no matter what is the value of required. But multiple constructors can be marked with `@Autowired` but all of them must have required=false.

Check this [page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17455) where I raised the issue. And this [page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23263) where I made the request to improve documentation.